Missing classes detected while running R8
I have a multi module project setup like this:

app module

presentation module (Android module)

domain module (Kotlin module)

data module (Android module)


The dependency graph
presentation -> domain <- data
And app has dependency in all modules.
The code is the following:
domain module:
interface RemoteVenuesDataSource {
    suspend fun getVenues(): Result<List<Venue>, DataError.Network>
}

class GetVenuesUseCase(
    private val remoteVenuesDataSource: RemoteVenuesDataSource,
) {
    suspend operator fun invoke() = remoteVenuesDataSource.getVenues()
}

data module:
   @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideHttpClient(): HttpClient {
        return HttpClientFactory().build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRemoteVenuesDataSource(
        httpClient: HttpClient,
    ): RemoteVenuesDataSource {
        return KtorVenuesRemoteDataSource(
            httpClient = httpClient
        )
    }

presentation module:
class GetVenuesUseCase(
    private val remoteVenuesDataSource: RemoteVenuesDataSource,
) {
    suspend operator fun invoke() = remoteVenuesDataSource.getVenues()
}

@Provides
@ViewModelScoped
fun provideGetVenuesUseCase(
    remoteVenuesDataSource: RemoteVenuesDataSource,
): GetVenuesUseCase {
    return GetVenuesUseCase(
        remoteVenuesDataSource
    )
}

and this gets injected into the viewmodel:
@HiltViewModel
class VenuesViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val getVenuesUseCase: GetVenuesUseCase,
  
)

and this viewmodel gets used like this:
@Composable
fun VenuesScreenRoot(
    viewModel: VenuesViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
) {
    Text(text = "Temp")
    viewModel.temp()
}

And in the app module:
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            TempTheme {
                Scaffold(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) { innerPadding ->
                    Greeting(
                        name = "Android",
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
                    )

                    VenuesScreenRoot(
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

When I run the build in debug everything works, but If I switch to the release build (minify enabled) it breaks.
The app module generates this missing_rules.txt
# Please add these rules to your existing keep rules in order to suppress warnings.
# This is generated automatically by the Android Gradle plugin.
-dontwarn com.temp.data.di.SingletonModule
-dontwarn com.temp.data.di.SingletonModule_ProvideHttpClientFactory
-dontwarn com.temp.data.di.SingletonModule_ProvideRemoteVenuesDataSourceFactory
-dontwarn com.temp.presentation.theme.ThemeKt
-dontwarn com.temp.presentation.venus.VenuesScreenKt
-dontwarn com.temp.presentation.venus.VenuesViewModel

and this error message:
Missing class com.temp.data.di.SingletonModule (referenced from: com.temp.data.di.SingletonModule com.temp.DaggerHoaxCoffeeApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC$Builder.singletonModule and 5 other contexts)
Missing class com.temp.data.di.SingletonModule_ProvideHttpClientFactory (referenced from: java.lang.Object com.temp.DaggerHoaxCoffeeApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC$SingletonCImpl$SwitchingProvider.get())
Missing class com.temp.data.di.SingletonModule_ProvideRemoteVenuesDataSourceFactory (referenced from: java.lang.Object com.temp.DaggerHoaxCoffeeApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC$SingletonCImpl$SwitchingProvider.get())
Missing class com.temp.data.di.SingletonModule_ProvideTempFactory (referenced from: java.lang.Object com.temp.DaggerHoaxCoffeeApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC$SingletonCImpl$SwitchingProvider.get())
Missing class com.temp.presentation.theme.ThemeKt (referenced from: void com.temp.ComposableSingletons$MainActivityKt$lambda-3$1.invoke(androidx.compose.runtime.Composer, int))
Missing class com.temp.presentation.venus.VenuesScreenKt (referenced from: void com.hoax.coffee.ComposableSingletons$MainActivityKt$lambda-1$1.invoke(androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues, androidx.compose.runtime.Composer, int))
Missing class com.temp.presentation.venus.VenuesViewModel (referenced from: void com.temp.ComposableSingletons$MainActivityKt$lambda-1$1.invoke(androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues, androidx.compose.runtime.Composer, int))

and
Caused by: [CIRCULAR REFERENCE: com.android.tools.r8.internal.g: Missing class com.temp.data.di.SingletonModule (referenced from: com.temp.data.di.SingletonModule com.temp.DaggerHoaxCoffeeApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC$Builder.singletonModule and 5 other contexts)

But I dont want to add keep files into the app module because I would have to add so much in the end which I created I would lose the meaning of R8.
As you can see I also created the Theme file and a VenusViewModel in the presentation package and R8 also complains about it.
If I would have to add every viewmodel which I create in the presentation package then R8 would just lose its meaning.
agp = "8.5.1"

hilt = "2.51.1"

kotlin = "2.0.0"

ksp = "1.8.10-1.0.9"


I had the same error in my multimodule project after upgrading Gradle Plugin and the reason was this:  https://developer.android.com/build/releases/past-releases/agp-8-4-0-release-notes#library-classes-shrunk
So I set minifyEnabled to true only in my app module and to false in all other modules. Another option is to add
android.disableMinifyLocalDependenciesForLibraries=false to the gradle.properties file.

Will my library code be minified or obfuscated if minifyEnabled is set to false in the library module?
